# Landsat image exported from Google Earth Engine not displaying correctly in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google-earth-engine, landsat

I have run a script to produce a land use classification clipped to my study site using google earth engine. However, when i export the classified image and open it in ArcMap , the image is cut off at the bottom.

Could someone assist?

Below is an example of what I am talking about. The link to my script is also available below.

[image]

Script : https://code.earthengine.google.com/94fcd072ee8a9cbf06bf6142e98fe156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happened is because of how the `Export.image` process works. Paraphrasing the documentation provided by Earth Engine which states: "If no region is specified for export, the region defaults to the viewport at the time of invocation." Basically, you were only viewing part of the image when exporting and it cut off the bottom.

Generally, it is good practice to provide the `region` parameters when exporting images to avoid this problem. Here is an your example that exports the full image (starting at line 128):

```
///////////EXPORT  CLASSIFIED IMAGE//////////////

var exportRegion = studysite.geometry().bounds()

Export.image.toDrive({
   image: composite,
   description: 'LU',
   folder: 'GEE data',
   scale: 30,
   region: exportRegion,
   fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
 });
```

Notice that the `exportRegion` variable is extracted from the study area you provided and then passed as a parameter in the export task. Here is the [full working link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e41aeeab1cc696aee490189945119a1).